# Babel-node not lncluding .graphql files in build

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, babeljs

I'm loading .graphql files like this:

```
import { join } from 'path'
import { loadSchemaSync } from '@graphql-tools/load'
import { GraphQLFileLoader } from '@graphql-tools/graphql-file-loader'
import { addResolversToSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema'
import resolvers from './resolvers'
const schema = loadSchemaSync(join(__dirname, './typedefs/*.graphql'), { loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()] })

const schemaWithResolver = addResolversToSchema({
  schema,
  resolvers
})
export default schemaWithResolver
```

When I build for production, the folder `./typedefs` is not included in the build output (dist).

This is the build cmd: `"build-babel": "babel ./src -s -d dist"`

How do include .graphql extensions in the babel cmd above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `--copy-files` flag to include non-js files.

Changing the build command to this should work:

```
"build-babel": "babel ./src -s -d dist --copy-files"
```